# The value of a variable inside my if function will not update (flask, javascript (jquery))

Tags: javascript, python, jquery, database, flask

When there is no owner assigned `equipment_co_owner_id` will be '-1' but when there is an owner the `equipment_co_owner_id` has to change to the ID of that person (comes from .db file). Since the name of a person is LASTNAME Firstname I split it up so I can implement the SQL. The python function returns the correct JSON file.
`var ID` also gives me the correct ID, but the code doesn't assign `ID` to `equipment_co_owner_id`. Does anyone know how I can fix this?

Python code

```
@equipment.route('/getUserIDByUserName', methods=['GET'])
def get_user_id_by_user_name():
    db = Database()
    user_last_name = request.args.get('user_last_name')
    user_name = request.args.get('user_name')

    sql = 'SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_name LIKE "%' + user_name + '%" AND user_last_name LIKE "%' + user_last_name + '%"'
    db.conn.row_factory = db.dict_factory
    c = db.conn.cursor()
    c.execute(sql)
    return json.dumps(c.fetchall())
```

JS code

```
    var equipment_co_owner_id = -1;
    if ($("#eq_co_owner_id").val() != "") {
        var coOwnerFullName = $("#eq_co_owner_id").val();
        // naam in hoofdletters = achternaam
        var coOwnerLastName = coOwnerFullName.match(/(\b[A-Z][A-Z]+|\b[A-Z]\b)/g)[0];
        var coOwnerName = coOwnerFullName.split(" ").splice(-1);
        argString = "?user_last_name=" + coOwnerLastName + "&user_name=" + coOwnerName
        $.get("/getUserIDByUserName" + argString, function (data, status) {
            var ID = JSON.parse(data)[0].ID;
            equipment_co_owner_id = ID;
        });
    }
```

Comment: Hi, you need to put that value inside your textbox using `$("#eq_co_owner_id").val(ID)`